# Cookie session store's behavior after server restart in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I have a rails 4 application with a cookie session store. After I reboot application, it seems like user sessions are recreated and the browser receives a new session ID but the user does not need to login as a new session holds last info; however I would like to init the session for example to set correct locale - is there any event I could use for that purpose?
I have verified that it is not the devise restoring current_user from the cookie so I assume it is some kind of a session restart.

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.15)
  * actionpack (4.1.15)
  * actionview (4.1.15)
  * activemodel (4.1.15)
  * activerecord (4.1.15)
  * activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.6)
  * activesupport (4.1.15)
  * ar-octopus (0.8.6)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6.2)
  * bcrypt (3.1.11)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
  * bootstrap_form (2.6.0)
  * builder (3.2.3)
  * bundler (1.13.6)
  * byebug (9.0.6)
  * cocoon (1.2.9)
  * coffee-rails (4.1.1)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
  * daemons (1.2.3)
  * devise (3.5.3)
  * devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.5)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
  * exception_notification (4.1.4)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * faraday (0.9.2)
  * flipper (0.7.5)
  * flipper-ui (0.7.5)
  * hashie (3.4.4)
  * i18n (0.8.1)
  * json (1.8.6)
  * jwt (1.5.4)
  * mail (2.6.4)
  * mime-types (3.1)
  * mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
  * mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
  * minitest (5.10.1)
  * multi_json (1.12.1)
  * multi_logger (0.1.0)
  * multi_xml (0.5.5)
  * multipart-post (2.0.0)
  * net-ldap (0.11)
  * oauth2 (1.0.0)
  * omniauth (1.3.1)
  * omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.4.1 1cd603b)
  * omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * protected_attributes (1.1.3)
  * rack (1.5.5)
  * rack-protection (1.5.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.1.15)
  * railties (4.1.15)
  * rake (11.2.2)
  * responders (1.1.2)
  * sass (3.4.22)
  * sass-rails (5.0.4)
  * sprockets (3.6.1)
  * sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
  * thin (1.7.0)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * tilt (2.0.5)
  * tiny_tds (1.0.5)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * tzinfo-data (1.2016.5)
  * uglifier (3.0.0)
  * warden (1.2.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I am changing secret_key_base to invalidate all sessions during the restart but it would be great to know how to handle the situation without it